Docker image build issue, stuck in RUN
I need to create an image of a REST API project created with express. In the image construction phase everything is executed correctly but I get stuck even for hours in the RUN phase but it doesn't make any errors as you can see from the screen everything is executed correctly and I get the log message that I entered for synchronization of the db but I don't understand why the build doesn't finish, I also attach the DockerFile

FROM node:20.14.0

WORKDIR /user/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm start

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js" ]


I add that I tried several times to redo the build also by inserting the --no-cache option

Well, npm start runs the web server in foreground, so this is a "never ending command", so yes this is normal. What you really want to do is to have your npm start as the CMD of thet container: CMD ["npm", "start"] and get rid of that RUN statement.
